# Can't connect [Logged on failed AccountLogin due wrong password]

Tags: authentication, azerothcore

i just did a fresh setup of [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/64aa475d0f605bb31b784722e555ec166b22b09c)

Problem: I can't login into wow, I've tried multiple accounts and it still says:

> Wrong password or account

Logging enabled and settings of `realmlist` table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: are you using the account name or the email when trying to log in? you should never use the email

Comment: I did- .account set password test1 ab ab  ... Trying to login with name: test1 pass: ab

Comment: I did also .acc create lol lol  and i tried name: lol password: lol    -- never tried email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2017 make sure you have version `15.9.17` or higher (you can see the version in Help -> About).

I had a similar issue using older an older Visual Studio version: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/2358